React MUI Avatar div height defaults to static value (40px)
I have a MUI Avatar element on my page:
<Avatar
  sx={{ width: 180, height: "auto", maxHeight: 180, margin: 2 }}
  variant="square"
  alt={""}
  src={
    global.config.baseUrl +
    "/image/logo" +
    this.state.user.userId +
    ".jpg"
  }
/>

this generates the following DOM:
<div class="MuiAvatar-root MuiAvatar-square css-eqjmj4">
    <img alt="" src="/image/logo1.jpg" class="MuiAvatar-img css-1hy9t21">
</div>

with the following css class:
.css-eqjmj4 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
  width: 180px;
  max-height: 180px;
  margin: 16px;
}

I want the width set to exactly 180px, with the height to scale proportionately (up to a maxHeight of 180px)
For some reason the css class hard-codes the height to height: 40px;
How can I override that?

it seems like this was logged as an issue at one point, but not followed up: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/39106

Testing in a code Sandbox, but with a custom URL, the avatar seems to take the size being passed on. Can you provide more context as to the CSS around it maybe, or the image? Without a reproducible example it is difficult to help.

Seems like the square variant of the Avatar is just CSS of height and width behind the scene, which isn't exactly very intuitive.
My suggestion is to -- add the style of aspect-ratio (which is supported by all the modern browsers) yourself with the value of 1 / 1 so the code will look like this.
<Avatar
  sx={{
    width: 180,
    aspectRatio: "1 / 1", // <-- look here
    height: "auto",
    maxHeight: 180,
    margin: 2,
  }}
  variant="square" // doesn't matter anymore, can omit
  src="/static/images/avatar/3.jpg"
/>

This will work with max-height when you set the width that is larger than it.
Heres a working example
